# Defining a new list so that modifications do not affect the original without importing copy

Tags: python, list

I know that there have been several similar discussions on this topic and I have tried to implement at least one (a list comprehension). The main issue is that my original list (it is actually a matrix set up as a list of lists) is being modified by part of my code, but I can not seem to figure out why.

Here is the code that I have

```
def eliminate_row_column(mat,k,l):
    new_matrix = [i for i in mat]      #creates a new temp matrix
    new_matrix.pop(k)        #eliminates the kth row
    for i in range(len(new_matrix)):
        new_matrix[i].pop(l)     #eliminates the lth column
    return new_matrix
```

It appears to be removing the kth element (the kth row) without modifying the original. However, when I enter the for loop it appears to be modifying the original input list.

It appears that using a deep copy might resolve the issue, but I will need this code to work in context where (students) can not import in.

I am not a programmer by training and this one is giving me a bit of a headache.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour]. It would really help to provide a [mre] to demonstrate the problem. It also might help to pose this as a question instead of as a problem statement. You can [edit] the question. See [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: You only need deepcopy if you need to copy to an unknown depth. If you know it's always a 2-dimensional matrix, just use nested list comprehensions.

Comment: You are correct (from below) that I am not allowing them to use NumPy. Instead they have to code different matrix operations from "scratch" (this will be part of an incomplete determinant calculator that they will finish).  If I use the nested list comprehension should that create a new list that they can modify without effecting the original matrix?

Answer (score 1):

In this line, `i` references the existing lists, which are not copied.

```
new_matrix = [i for i in mat]
```

You can simply copy them:

```
new_matrix = [i.copy() for i in mat]
```

---

By the way, for what it's worth, a list of lists is not really a matrix. You could use a [NumPy array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.html) if you wanted a proper matrix.

Comment: If they can't import `copy`, then they almost certainly can't import `numpy`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Barmar for the correct solution. I am including the corrected code below to show the fix. Obviously you can use numpy instead, but this works without it.

```
def eliminate_row_column(mat,k,l):
    new_matrix = [[t for t in row ] for row in mat]    #creates a new temp matrix
    new_matrix.pop(k)        #eliminates the kth row
    for i in range(len(new_matrix)):
        new_matrix[i].pop(l)     #eliminates the lth column
    return new_matrix
```